Natural Deduction, question on Gentzen notation
Can anyone explain the function of the brackets, curved tent like A and C in this picture? Specifically forms EB, FE, and NE? These are eliminationright?
This page explains some of the notation so it is similar to modern, but lacks explanation of the rules and I think it’s wrong because Ex is elimination not Bx. Wikipedia has a good explanation what looks similar.


See Falsum

The curved tent $⋏$ is now written $\bot$.  It means falsity or contradiction.  Gentzen also used a down-pointing tent $⋎$ where we would write $\top$, but there are no useful deduction rules for it.
Rules are read top to bottom, as today: from the constructions above the line, one can conclude the formula below the line.
Rules ending in "E" are introduction rules and 'E' is for Einführung.  The elimination rules are labeled 'B' for Beseitigung.  Rule "EE" is existence (Existenz) introduction; "EB" is existence elimination.
The brackets like $[\mathfrak A]$ mean "assume $\mathfrak A$".  For example, "FE", which is implication introduction, (Folge Einführung), says (above the line) that if you have a deduction of $\mathfrak B$ from an assumption of $\mathfrak A$, then (below the line) you may conclude  ${\mathfrak A}\supset{\mathfrak B}$, which means that  $\mathfrak A$  implies $\mathfrak B$.
Similarly, "NE" is negation introduction. If from an assumption $[\mathfrak A]$ we can deduce a contradiction  $⋏$ , then we can conclude $\lnot \mathfrak A$, that $\mathfrak A$ is false.
I think the way you should approach this is by getting a modern copy of the rules, putting them side-by-side with these, and then comparing.  They look almost exactly the same.

What is the purpose of the gothic C? It’s in OB and EB and I can’t make sense of what it’s purpose is.

The OB rule is for disjunction (oder) elimination. It says that if you have deduced ${\mathfrak A}\lor {\mathfrak B}$, and if you can deduce $\mathfrak C$ by assuming either $\mathfrak A$ or $\mathfrak B$, then this is sufficient to deduce $\mathfrak C$. This question is no longer about the historical notation, but about the most elementary ideas of natural deduction itself, and is off-topic for this site. I suggest you read a textbook on logic. The Gallier book Logic for Computer Science is not expensive.  https://store.doverpublications.com/products/9780486780825

I hadn't noticed this before but there's a real defect in the rules as written: the introduction rules for $\forall-$ and $\exists-$ appear identical!  There's an important contextual difference that Gentzen hasn't included, which is that in the $\forall$ rule, $\mathfrak a$ must be a free variable, whereas in the $\exists$ rule it can be any term. I suppose he explains this in the accompanying text.
